# MyEclipse Mobile Web Simulator Unsupported Browser?

Tags: android, cordova, myeclipse

I am building out a Cordova mobile app in MyEclipse and using the Mobile Web Simulator. Suddenly, I began receiving an "Unsupported Browser" warning in the simulator window, indicating that "only Chrome and Chromium based browsers are supported." But it was working fine, and obviously I have Chrome installed. I tried restarting MyEclipse but that didn't help. Anyone seen this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Check the location of your mobile simulator browser. From the Window menu, select Preferences and then the MyEclipse/Mobile Tools/Mobile Web Simulator page. You can select the location of your Chrome browser there. I'm not sure if there is a minimum release of Chrome that is required but it's probably best to ensure that you have the latest release.

Comment: I checked that and it is correct, and I confirmed I am on the latest Chrome build. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what the problem is. You said it worked and then didn't. Something must have changed between those two conditions; do you have any idea what changed? What OS are you on, and which release of MyEclipse? You could try it with a new workspace just to check if there is anything in your current workspace that might be affecting this.

Answer (score 0):

myeclipse2014 can not run myEclipse web Simulator application solution:

1. Manually delete the MyEclipse Sim Chrome profile directory.On Windows the chrome profile can be found at path similar to `<userhome>\AppData\Local\Temp\myeclipse_mobilewebsimulator_userdata\`
2. Close the simulator before deleting this directory.
3. Delete the directory above
4. Launch the simulator

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick and simple solution to the "unsupported browser" issue. Go to the Window menu(in Myeclipse),then "Preferences", click "Reset simulator settings",hit apply and to my surprise...the Mobile Web Simulator was back. Why it suddenly didnt work I have no idea. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Chrome to no avail either. Hope it works for you.Good luck!